# PySpark, How to simply count the number of each cluster in Kmeans model?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I trained a Kmeans model:

```
kmeans = KMeans(k=20, seed=1)
df.show()
kmeans_model = kmeans.fit(df)
```

I just want to simply count how many elements in each cluster, but I can't find a simple way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the pyspark document. Here is the answer:

```
summary = kmeans_model.summary
print(summary.clusterSizes)
```

Reference:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans